# How can I manually / programmatically create a DataRow?

Tags: c#, system.data

My project's codebase has a legacy method that takes a DataRow as a parameter for which I would like to create a unit test method.

How can I manually create a DataRow object to pass to the method?  The [`System.Data.DataRow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx) class doesn't have a public-facing constructor.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A DataRow can be created by creating a new DataTable instance, adding columns to the DataTable corresponding to the "keys" that the DataRow needs to have, and then calling `NewRow()` on the DataTable. For example:

```
DataTable usersTable = new DataTable();

usersTable.Columns.Add("FirstName");
usersTable.Columns.Add("LastName");
usersTable.Columns.Add("Email");

DataRow userRow = usersTable.NewRow();

userRow["FirstName"] = "Elmer";
userRow["LastName"] = "Example";
userRow["Email"] = "elmer@example.com";
usersTable.Rows.Add(userRow);
```

Comment: usersTable.Rows.Add(userRow);

Answer (score 10):

You should note that if the Unit Test needed to enforce type constraints on the `DataColumnCollection` (Columns) for the `DataTable` - you can use the overloaded constructor of the `DataColumn` class to include the expected `Type`.

```
        var dt = new DataTable();
        
        var dc = new DataColumn("Age", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);
        var dr = dt.NewRow();

        dr["Age"] = "test"; // throws an ArgumentException
        //Input string was not in a correct format. Couldn't store<test> in Age Column.  Expected type is Int32.

        //should it succeed
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Comment: You also need to add this row to the datatable. Do this `dt.Rows.Add(dr);`

Comment: You can specify the type as part of the add now:
`dt.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));`