# How to create data table in c#?

Tags: c#

I have tried to create a data table in C#, but I want to achieve similar results to these shown in this screenshot:

[image]

I can create dynamic columns but can not create rows.

```
DataTable dt_bq = new DataTable();
dt_bq.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
dt_bq.Columns.Add("12/8", typeof(string));
dt_bq.Columns.Add("13/8", typeof(string));
dt_bq.Columns.Add("Total", typeof(string));
DataRow dr_tot = dt_bq.NewRow();
```

Comment: [DataRowExtensions.SetField Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowextensions.setfield?view=netframework-4.8). Remember that `.NewRow` will only create an instance of new row, you need manually add it to the datatable later.

Comment: Got it. But I wanted to achieve a result similar to the image.

Comment: So what is the problem? Specific problem, not just "not working" please ;)

Comment: You want to display this on your `View` or only need it in your backend to process your data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I manually / programmatically create a DataRow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44010345/how-can-i-manually-programmatically-create-a-datarow)

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netframework-4.8

```cs
// Setting up header of table
DataTable dt_bq = new DataTable();
dt_bq.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
dt_bq.Columns.Add("12/8", typeof(string));
dt_bq.Columns.Add("13/8", typeof(string));
dt_bq.Columns.Add("14/8", typeof(string));
dt_bq.Columns.Add("Total", typeof(string));

// Insert rows for that table
DataRow dr_tot = dt_bq.NewRow();
dr_tot["Date"] = "Issue Qty";
dr_tot["12/8"] = "10";
dr_tot["13/8"] = "20";
dr_tot["14/8"] = "30";
dr_tot["Total"] = "60";
dt_bq.Rows.Add(dr_tot);

dr_tot = dt_bq.NewRow();
dr_tot["Date"] = "Retrun Qty";
dr_tot["12/8"] = "5";
dr_tot["13/8"] = "20";
dr_tot["14/8"] = "30";
dr_tot["Total"] = "55";
dt_bq.Rows.Add(dr_tot);

dr_tot = dt_bq.NewRow();
dr_tot["Date"] = "Balance";
dr_tot["12/8"] = "5";
dr_tot["13/8"] = "0";
dr_tot["14/8"] = "0";
dr_tot["Total"] = "5";
dt_bq.Rows.Add(dr_tot);
```

You can add rows with column's name as index to the row. Then insert that row to the table.